# Return multiple files in Get request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am using asp net web api. I need to create an update request to my client. Example i need my client to retreive all necessery files for making an update om his application.
So i have create a get method witch converts all files from server to bytes, then i am place them inside a list and i send it to my client. There are 15 total files. Total size is 150mbytes and after compression is 70mbytes.

```
public class DataFiles
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
}

public IHttpActionResult Get(string version)
    {
        var mItems = new List<DataFiles>();
        var path = "C:\\Versions\\" + version;
        if (Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(path);//Assuming Test is your Folder
            FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*"); //Getting all files
            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                mItems.Add(new DataFiles
                {
                    FileName = file.Name,
                    Data = Compress(File.ReadAllBytes(file.FullName))
                });

            }
        }
        return Ok(mItems);
    }

 public static byte[] Compress(byte[] data)
    {
        var output = new MemoryStream();
        using (var dstream = new DeflateStream(output, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
        {
            dstream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
        return output.ToArray();
    }
```

Is this method right? Shoud i send each file one by one? Should i use memorystream?

Comment: why not just pack all the files in a zip-archive, if you have to send them in one go?

Comment: Thank you, yes probably i will put them all inside an archive but is my method right? I read somewhere that is better to use stream method.

Comment: define "right", and i can answer your question. but i don't know your use case. i don't know your constraints.. does it _work_? is it, in your eyes, _maintainable and understandable_?  does it follow existing, applicable _standards_? then yes. maybe code review-stackexchange is a better fit for this question

Comment: Thank you Franz. I read that is better to not load all files in memory. I am not sure what is that mean

Comment: Is it better to use something like this?

Comment: public HttpResponseMessage Test()
{
    var path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/test.docx");;
    HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
    result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    
}